# Como executar via JS a ação de um botão de enviar email, cujo ID sempre muda?

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso executar a ação deste botão, que originariamente funciona com Control+Enter, utilizando um JS meu, mas as únicas coisas estáticas do botão são o `data-tooltip` e `aria-label`:

```
<div tabindex="1" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3 T-I-JW T-I-Zf-aw2" 
id=":go" role="button" aria-label="Enviar ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" 
data-tooltip="Enviar ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" unselectable="on" 
data-tooltip-delay="800">Enviar</div>
```

Prefiro uma solução sem simulação de teclas, que aja diretamente no elemento e me permita comandar o envio programaticamente.

Comment: Veja se a pergunta reflete sua necessidade, alterei baseado nos comentários que você fez na minha resposta. Por ora deletei a minha resposta original por não solucionar o seu problema, e também ajudar a atrair respostas novas.

Comment: Agora que eu percebi... Você quer acionar o botão de enviar do Google Mail por JS? Parece interessante, mas talvez tenha outros caminhos para chegar no resultado pretendido. Ponha os detalhes na pergunta, de repente este é um **[Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/)** e pode ser resolvido de outras maneiras.

Comment: Que ação pretende executar? O que espera que o usuário faça nesse botão e o que pretende que aconteça depois da ação do usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll). Esse método funciona de maneira similar ao jQuery, buscando por seletores CSS. Atente-se apenas ao [suporte dos navegadores a essa função](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) para saber se o alcance da mesma atende a sua necessidade.

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tooltip="Enviar ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬"]')[0]    
button.onclick = function(){ ... }
```

Comment: data-tooltip é um atributo , não um seletor css.

Comment: Onde eu disse que data-tooltip é um seletor css? [Attribute selectors](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) são seletores css

Comment: Ta funcionando blz

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro passo encontrar o botão. Sabemos que é uma div e que tem dois atributos que não mudam. Então:

```
 //buscamos todas as div
   var a = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

   //vemos a que tem o atributo que queremos
   for(var b=0; b<a.length; b++)
   {
     if(a[b].getAttribute("data-tooltip") == "Enviar ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬"
     {     
        var c= a[b];
        break;
     }
    }

    //cancelamos o evento ligado ás teclas
    try
    {
       c.addEventListener("keypress",function(e){e.preventDefault();return false;})
    } 
    catch(e)
    {
       c.attachEvent("keypress",function(e){e.returnValue = false;return false;})
    }
```

Se pede para carregar em duas teclas então, quase de certeza temos um evento keypress, que tento cancelar. O ideal seria saber que função o evento chama e utilizar o método removeEventListener();.

De qualquer forma, pode utilizar a carregar da primeira tecla para realizar a ação que pretende. Se puder colocar um pouco mais de código.